# Multisite homepage stuck to twenty-twentythree (only for logged-out users)

Tags: multisite, homepage, frontpage, bug

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now...

I have a sub-domain WordPress multisite install with the following structure:

```
// Wordpress path
https://example.com/cms
// Wordpress home
https://example.com/

//Other sites
https://sub.example.com
```

I have the twenty-twentytwo theme active on the main site, and a set of parent theme + child theme active on all the other sites. (child theme activated)

### The problem

While logged in with any user (super-admin to subscriber, or even with a user with no capability) I can see the subdomain site as they are supposed to be: the home page uses the front-page.php template from the child theme and shows the custom content.

If visited when logged out, **the same page shows a default twenty-twentythree home page**, with fake mockup content, as shown below.

I've tried cleaning the cache, both from the browser and from the hosting. I've tried activating twenty-twentytwo but the problem remains: nothing makes the homepage change from what you can see below.

Any thougths?

[image]

Comment: sounds like you have a caching plugin or a caching CDN such as cloudflare active, can you be more specific when you say you cleared the cache, _which_ caches and _how?_